# onnx model import problem when using nudenet library In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

```
from nudenet import NudeDetector

detector = NudeDetector()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "anti_porn_bot.py", line 3, in 
detector = NudeDetector()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nudenet/detector.py", line 57, in **init**
self.detection_model = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(checkpoint_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 347, in **init**
self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options, disabled_optimizers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 384, in _create_inference_session
sess = C.InferenceSession(session_options, self._model_path, True, self._read_config_from_model)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.InvalidProtobuf: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 7 : INVALID_PROTOBUF : Load model from /root/.NudeNet/detector_v2_default_checkpoint.onnx failed:Protobuf parsing failed.

How can I solve this problem؟

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful solution for your issue:

Instead of using detector_v2_default_checkpoint_back.onnx, you can replace it with the following file: https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/detector_v2_default_checkpoint.onnx

I found this link in a thread on the forum:
https://forum.opencv.org/t/unable-to-import-onnx-model/3730

Hope this resolves your problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34544976)